# "something in her tone" vs "her tone"

Tags: sentence-choice

The sentence is

> Something in her **tone** reminded me of the other girl's "I think he killed a man," and had the effect of stimulating my curiosity. - 
>   "The Great Gatsby", F. Scott Fitzgerald

If I rewrite the sentence as "Her tone reminded me of the other ...", does it have the same meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> her tone

is simply the tone of her voice

> something in her tone

refers to some quality of her voice, such as nervousness, hidden anger, happiness etc., that was perceived by the listener (the *something*). Usually it is an indication but not obvious.

Comment: (Assuming the question should be answered) this doesn't really answer the question that was asked.  OP didn't ask for a *definition* of tone, but is asked whether the rewrite is good English.